# Ubuntu 15.04 Nvidia NVS 5200m not working and mini display port not working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, nvidia-optimus

so I have about 3 issues that may be all related.

I have a thinkpad T430s with nvidia optimus.

I cannot for the life of me get the GPu working with bumblebee (used all the guides posted around here) and the nvidia drivers from the repos, cause the login screen to flicker between black (showing CLI mode with some info) and the login screen, disabling the nvidia GPU fixes this. I managed to get it working once through repo driver but was greeted with a kernel panic.

secondly my mini displayport wont work, VGA works but the mini display port isn't which is about to send me back to windows.

third when using VGA I get screen tearing on the second monitor.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So update, on Ubuntu, it cannot work with unity or Light DM.

using ubuntu-gnome I have it working like a charm albit some serious screen tearing and no sync to vblank option in the nvidia settings manager.